# Dividing a certain area into 1 km x 1 km square grids

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude

I have a map of a specific area (with about 1600 km width and 600 km height) and I will cover this entire area -which is not a straight shape like a rectangle or a square- with 1 km x 1 km square grids. I'm thinking of giving the starting latitude and longitude as the upper leftmost extreme point of my area -with that point being the upper left corner of the first square grid- and go from there. What would be the best way for me calculate the corners of all the square grids that will cover the my map? -I'm using C++ to calculate the corner variables for every square grid and then check if a given lat-lon pair falls within any one of these squares.- Thanks.

Comment: See my answer [for your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044467/is-there-a-way-to-divide-a-map-into-square-grids-and-retrieve-latitude-longitude/12049548#12049548)